# How to MINUS sum of values from sum of values php and mysql

Tags: php

am very new in php, and I have serious question to get the answer, I hope you will help me.

I have a table on mysql named "Payment" with the following fields

```
(School_fee  |  Fee_setting  |  Trans_port  |   trans_setting)
```

in fields setting of all fields i set the actual total amount of money which student suppose to pay for appropriate service per 3 month, and student can pay for  installment, So guys I want when I set may be 100000 at once in fee_setting, and when student come and pay 20000 as School_fee the amount will be reducted each time when student pay a school_fee . this means `(fee_setting)` it will  reduct total number of school_fee payed by a certain student.

I have the codes but this reduct only first student and others student the results comes with negative sign(-), Am confused i don't know where the problems is.

**Here the codes:**

```
echo $results['SUM(fee_setting)'] - $results ['SUM(school_fee)']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `abs()` to avoid negative values :

```
echo abs($results['SUM(fee_setting)'] - $results ['SUM(school_fee)'])."</td>";
```

Comment: thank u Guy, the (-) sign disappear but it doesn't minus the amount payed like a first student. I want when I set certain amount once in fee_setting field, this amount suppose to subtract each row in school_fee when any student pay the fee.Sorry may be my explanation was not clear. Thank u in advance, please help me

Comment: I want to make it very clear, for now it require that, I must set each time the same amount in fee_setting row when student pay school_fee so that to subtract. Me I don't want to set every time.